# Centos 8 user administration GUI

Tags: centos, users

Is there a more detailed user admin GUI than the default Gnome/settings app?
"Settings" only shows desktop users, and no groups.
Or, it's possible to call it from the command line as root or SU, then what's it called?

(please don't mention system-config-users, it doesn't seem available on Centos 8:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [RHEL8 Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/getting-started-with-system-administration_configuring-basic-system-settings#getting-started-with-managing-user-accounts_getting-started-with-system-administration) shows you how to use command line tools and the Cockpit web GUI to manage users.  The old tools like `system-config-users` are not available on CentOS8.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found a GUI to administer both users and groups.
It's still browser based, I'm afraid, and while proprietary, it's still free. It's called "webmin": https://www.webmin.com/download.html